# Spring cloud data flow on kubernetes doesnt show the streams section

Tags: spring, kubernetes

Installed spring cloud data flow on kubernetes following the procedure here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.7.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_installation

After install console is up, but only shows apps and audit records on the dashbaord, stream and task designers are missing. Are there additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

Enable use skipper in the server-deployment.yaml by uncommenting the following lines seemed to have done the trick.

name: SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI
value: 'http://${SKIPPER_SERVICE_HOST}/api'
- name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SKIPPER_ENABLED
value: 'true'

Also changed some services to NodePort instead of ClusterIP to connect from local machine.